# Equal padding between 3 and 4 columned grid

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to only add *inner* paddings/spacing to three columns in a grid floating to each other. So the padding will not be applied to the left of the first column and to the right of the last column.

The illustration below demonstrate what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

For a grid with two columns, I simply did the following:

```
.grid .size-1of2 {
    width: 50%
}
.grid .column.size-1of2:first-of-type {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.grid .column.size-1of2:last-of-type {
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

And it worked, as the space between the columns what 10px spot-on! However, now when I try to do the same to a grid with 3, 4 and 5 columns. Things just get messy and mathy!

Here is what I have so far for the three columned grid:

```
.grid .size-1of3 {
    width: 33.33333%
}
.grid .column.size-1of3 {
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
.grid .column.size-1of3:first-of-type {
    padding: 0 7.5px 0 0;
}
.grid .column.size-1of3:last-of-type {
    padding: 0 0 0 8.5px;
}
```

The html is really simple, note: The .column's are generated by the plugin(1) described below:

```
<div class="grid columns3">
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class"column size-1of3">
     <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The question is:** 
What is the best approach to solve this problem? having *10px* *inner* gab between the columns with maintaining *consistent* columns widths?

I am using this **plugin (1)** to create the grid system http://savvior.org - the plugin purely creates the columns requested and sort the elements inside it equally. So the padding is simply a styling feature which the plugin does not do but I am trying to implement.

**LIVE TEST SITE: http://loai.directory/test-grid**

Comment: Please share some significant HTML code too

Comment: It is not enough. I created a jsfiddle with your code (http://jsfiddle.net/dd3m67js/ for the 2-column grid, and http://jsfiddle.net/hesxfpoj/ for the 3-column grid) and it is displayed incorrectly in both cases (according to your question, it should look ok for the 2-column grid). You are not providing all the information needed to help you: are you using any library/framework? what is the css for the `.grid`? and for `.column`?

Comment: I just realized there was a typo and the styles were not included, just fixed it, but still not working in http://jsfiddle.net/dd3m67js/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/hesxfpoj/1/ for the 2-column and 3-column grid respectively

Comment: Here you go guys:  http://loai.directory/test-grid thank you for your help! I have coded the areas with colours - I think it will help. We bascially need to remove the RED spaces that is on the sides of each .grid.